# How to implement Redis TOPK for finding top liked posts with hashtag

Tags: redis

Had a question, i'm not sure if there is a REDIS structure (or group of structures?) that can handle this.
I already have a solution, but it doesnt scale at all...

So, I want to track the top `100 trending hashtags`.
✅ This first part is easy using the `TOPK` REDIS structure.

❌ The problem is, that for each of those top trending hashtags, i want to track the `50 top liked posts`.
So a result can look something like this

```
1.  #Cars       -> [p1, p10, p8.  ....etc till count of 50]
2.  #Politics   -> [p100, p6, p77 ....etc till count of 50]
.
.
.
100 #RandomVids -> [p22, p25, p0  ....etc till count of 50]
```

I guess there is no REDIS structure out of the box that can help with this in a scalable manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do a`TOPK.RESERVE` for `top_hashes`. This will store the top hashes **Cars, Politics... RandomVids**
2. When a new post comes in with a hashtag, add the hashtag to `top_hashes`. Example, say a post with #cars comes in, add #cars to `top_hashes`.
3. Check to see if #cars was added. If it wasn't, then ignore. But if it *was*, then do another `TOPK.RESERVE` for `#cars` and then add the `post_id` to #cars.

So now we tracking `top_hashes` and also the posts within each hash.

When adding a hash to top_hashes using the TOPK.ADD command, if an item was popped off the top list, it will be returned. Check this return value to know if a hash tag popped off the list. If one *was* popped off the list, then you can go ahead and delete its corresponding hash from the other reserve.  So example, if #dogs popped #cars off the top_hashes list, then also go ahead and delete its #cars that was reserved earlier because its no longer necessary to track it.

This setup lets you track both top_hashes and also the corresponding posts connected to each hash. It also cleans up the corresponding posts connected to each hash when its no longer on the top_hashes list.

The only issue is at the ends. When example #cars gets poped of the top_hashes, all its tracked posts will deleted. if it is re-added, then all the posts will have to be tracked all over again.
A way to solve this is if you are keeping track of say top 10 hashes publicly, then internally keep track of say top 15 (or more). That way, you will not lose posts and have bad user experience.

Comment: This sounds do-able. But i wonder if its scalable? The other answer on this page makes it sound like it cant be this easy. Will await more responses before i respond.

Comment: gave this the answer as it was easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

There is no sketch data structure that directly supports your use case. Not in Redis, and most probably not in other libraries / data stores.

One thing I can suggest is to hold a top-k sketch for each hashtag in the hashtags top-k sketch (you can retrieve this list using `TOPK.LIST key`).

Two possible heuristic optimizations you can explore:

- Call `TOPK.LIST key` after each *m* inserts - and update your set of 'per-hashtag' top-k's according to the items in the hashtags list.
- Use `TOPK.LIST key WITHCOUNT` and keep a 'per-hashtag' top-k only for hashtags with count > n.

You should probably set the *topk* value in `TOPK.RESERVE key topk` for the hashtags list to *p* times the number you actually need.

Note that a theoretical expected error analysis would be quite complex.

Comment: Probably its me being a redis novice, but your answer is a bit hard for me to understand. I do have a TOPK list for the top level. But i do not understand the optimizations you have posted.

Comment: The first heuristic is about creating/remoing 'per hashag' sketches - not after processing each post, but after processing each m posts. The second heuristic is about creating new 'per hashtag' sketches only if the count > n.

Note that my answer and swift nub's answer are very similar.